# In MySQL if I create a user and grant privileges to the user, will dropping the user revoke privileges?

Tags: mysql, permissions

In MySQL, I created a user and granted all privileges to the user. I even granted proxy to user.

```
CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS 'testuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'testpass';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'testuser'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'testuser'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Now if I drop the user, will the user's privileges and proxy be revoked? Or do I need to manually revoke the user's privileges and proxy before I drop the user?

```
DROP USER IF EXISTS 'testuser'@'localhost';
```

Comment: Just test it? It'll take you 1 minute.

Comment: Yeah, I should have tested it. It seems dropping user revokes privileges and proxy.

Comment: You could query the `mysql.proxies_priv` table to see if the entry for the user is removed.

Comment: I just ended up doing `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'testuser'@'localhost'` after dropping the user and there was no results, which means grants are automatically revoked.

Comment: it store results in user tables within mysql if assigned on objects and if assigned on database level one entry in db table, once you drop the user both entries get deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The DROP USER statement removes one or more MySQL accounts and their **privileges**. It removes privilege rows for the account from all grant tables.

see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/drop-user.html

PROXY is a GRANT privilege so the proxy privilege should be deleted also.